# How can I read lines in a interval in Python?

Tags: python

I have a txt file, there are thousands of lines there, for example:

```
line 1 test
line 2 test
line 3 test 
line 4 test
line 5 test
line 6 test
line 7 test
line 8 test
line 9 test
```

I wish to read `line 1, line 4, line 7, line 10, line 13 ...` but ignore `line 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9...`. How can I read these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, I solved the problem by using `for i, line in enumerate(inputFile):`

Answer (score 9):

you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to iterate with a given `step`:

```
for line in itertools.islice(inputFile, None, None, 3):
```

1. Start with the first element (start = None)
2. End when the file does (end = None)
3. Step by 3 lines each time, ignore the rest.

Note that I'd much prefer to specify `step = 3` as a keyword but it seems islice doesn't support that. :(

This is conceptually similar to reading all the lines into memory then taking a slice of the resulting list:

```
all_lines = inputFile.readlines() #very memory inefficient
for line in all_lines[::3]: #step of 3, start is None and end is None.
```

However `islice`, much like everything else in `itertools`, is very memory efficient.